# IntelliJ IDEA: Find in files is not finding all the occurrences

Tags: intellij-idea

With IntelliJ 2021.1, I have noticed the search of files or words across a project is a bit flakey.

So if you paste a word to search with cmd + shift + f, it struggles to find all the words, and if you enter it from beginning it is better but still problematic.
Even double shift is struggling to find files.

I didn't notice such issues with previous version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266391).

Please add `-Didea.indexes.clear.non.indexable.file.data=false` into [Help | Edit Custom VM Options](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869) and invoke File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.. | Invalidate and Restart action as a workaround.