# Intellij Ultimate Search Everywhere not finding occurrencies (2023)

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij Ultimate Build #IU0232.10072027 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
I have a large Java+Extjs2 project where I can't find occurrences of simple text on files.
Following the exemple:
[evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUsei.png)

In one single file I have 21 occurrences and Search Everywhere couldn't find a single one!

It indeed is (or was) a known bug that a workaround is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67025163/intellij-idea-find-in-files-is-not-finding-all-the-occurrences). But no success!
Also tried deleting the .idea/ directory in the project.
Deleted the whole .cache/JetBrains/ directory.
Tried all together!
Nope
Do other people still have this in 2023? Is it new bug? Or am I the only one?

Comment: Please try using [Find in Files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html) instead of Search Everywhere feature. Does it work?

Comment: It did! But it actually helped me find where the actual problem was...
When I opened the Find in Files, I found out that there was an extension filter.
This filter was applied to the Search Everywhere as well but not shown there!
After removing the filter in Find in Files, the Search Everywhere started working properly.
Strangely, the only occurrence found in Search Everywhere was not applied to the filter in Find in Files!
This behavior was surely not expected.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Egor Klepikov, I was able to find the error.
I had previously set a filter in the [Find in Files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html), which also affects Search Everywhere, but isn't shown there. (It is not intuitive that it would behave like that)
After removing the filter in Find in Files, Search Everywhere started working properly.